# Internet Explorer not seeing Doctype

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

So I have been creating my own website and I have run into an issue were for some reason IE is not seeing my Doctype. My site is https://houdea.github.io/index.html, and if you were to open it in IE it would throw errors that makes no sense. Now below is the code for my header of that page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<title>Andrew Houde</title>

<!-- Style sheets -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/homepage.css" rel='stylesheet' charset="UTF-8">
<link href="css/aboutme.css" rel='stylesheet' charset="UTF-8">

</head>
```

Now If you go to this page https://houdea.github.io/site/contact.html it will work fine in IE. I just don't get why that is when they are the same code. So how do I get this to work in IE?

Comment: The response to GET `"https://houdea.github.io/site/index.html"` is full of \u0000 characters and starts with a BOM marker. Just cloned your repo, and indeed, https://github.com/houdea/houdea.github.io/blob/master/site/index.html is encoded as UTF-16LE. Reencode it as UT8.

Comment: @Kaiido how or where do I look to reencode it as UT8?

Comment: From your text editor, probably at saving.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks by the way I deleted the index file and created a new one and that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on your first line of code in **index.html**. The correct format of a html file should start with [**`<!DOCTYPE>`**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp). You need to remove this line then I think it will work in IE.

[image]

Comment: Yeah that was something I added to see if it changed anything and would throw an error. but it just does the same thing on IE with out it.